# Session being lost during Mobile Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: iphone, ios, vb.net, paypal

Very odd issue I am running into.

I have PayPal Express Checkout integrated and working perfectly on a website.

If I visit the website from an iPhone or iPad, the site goes through the entire Mobile express checkout, but then when it redirects back to my site, the session is lost. (I am storing the cartID and order variables in a session before they get directed to paypal)

This does not happen at all when using a regular computer browser. ONLY when using a mobile device.

The site is built in VB.net 4.0 running on IIS 7.5

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that because I was not on an HTTPS connection when the user selected "pay with paypal" that the session cleared when it redirected to the secure checkout. Once I updated this all worked perfectly.